# Forcing Hibernate not to use sp_execute for non-query

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Is there a way to force Hibernate not to use sp_execute?

Consider this code

```
String queryString = "SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
return query.executeUpdate();
```

It turns into **sp_prepare**, then **sp_execute** and that defeats the purpose: after executing this statement session deadlock priority is back to NORMAL

In .NET the following code would execute the statement directly and priority for the session stays LOW (as desired)

```
command = new SqlCommand("SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW", _Connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How to force Hibernate to send the statement in the same manner?

Comment: ORM's like hibernate have their limits. Once you reach them, it's best to abandon hibernate entirely, at least for the parts where you cross the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish that.

```
String statementText = "SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;";
Statement s = session.connection().createStatement();
s.execute(statementText);
```

However, connection() is "*deprecated and scheduled for removal in Hibernate 4.x*" (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526556/session-connection-deprecated-on-hibernate))