# Retrieving a value from Stored Procedure using Native SQL Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, native-sql

Below is the stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure 
proc_emp_name(v_emp out emp.emp_name%TYPE, v_empid in emp.emp_id%TYPE)
is
begin
select emp_name into v_emp from emp where emp_id = v_empid;
dbms_output.put_line('Emp Name: ' || v_emp);
dbms_output.put_line('Procedure created successfully!!!');
end;
```

I want to invoke this using Native SQL, followed this link but not sure how to retrieve the `OUT` parameter from the Procedure.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

Kindly let me know the simplest way to invoke the procedure and get the results out of it.

**EDIT**

As suggested, checking the docs, I modified the Proc having first parameter as a `SYS_REFCURSOR` as follows:

```
create or replace procedure
proc_empname_refcursor(v_empname OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, v_deptid in emp.emp_id%type)
is 
begin
open v_empname for select * from dept where dept_id = v_deptid;
end;
```

I am able to invoke it using `NamedQuery` but I don't want to add anything in the mapping files because of some other restrictions. I tried the below code for invoking the proc without using `NamedQuery` but it did not worked out:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
                "CALL proc_empname_refcursor(?, :deptId)")
                .addEntity(Dept.class)
                .setParameter("deptId", new Integer(2));

            List<Dept> departments = query.list();
            for(int i=0; i<departments.size(); i++){
                Dept department = (Dept)departments.get(i);
                System.out.println("Dept Id: " + department.getDeptId());
                System.out.println("Dept Name: " + department.getDeptName());
            }
```

I am getting the exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [CALL proc_empname_refcursor(?, :deptId)]
at     org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:319)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.verifyParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:201)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:145)
at com.jdbc.HibernateStartup.main(HibernateStartup.java:70)
```

Kindly let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to get an out parameter from a stored procedure using the following code in Hibernate and MS SQL Server:

```
@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
    Connection connection = session.connection();
    CallableStatement callable = null;
    try {
        callable = connection.prepareCall("execute [procedure] ?");
        callable.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        callable.execute();
        int id = callable.getInt(1);

        return id;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        (...)
    } finally {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Comment: `session.connection()` is deprecated, any idea on how to replace this?

Comment: Could you please let me know what Hibernate version you are using?

Comment: I am using HIbernate v3.2.5

Comment: Are you sure about `session.connection()` deprecation? I took a look at Hibernate javadocs at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/engine/SessionImplementor.html and couldn't find a deprecated tag

Comment: Check this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

Comment: I feel like this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526556/session-connection-deprecated-on-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

From [Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#sp_query):

You cannot use stored procedures with Hibernate unless you follow some procedure/function rules.

For Oracle, A function must return a result set. The first parameter of a procedure must be an OUT that returns a result set.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am able to invoke the proc as `named query` by adding it into mapping files. But now the problem is I dont want to add it in mapping and use it as named-query, rather I want to invoke it using directly using `createSQLQuery`. I tried that but got an exception: `org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [CALL proc_empname_refcursor(?, :deptId)]` I have updated my first post to  provide what exactly I tried, kindly let me know how to resolve this exception.

Comment: Remove the '?'. it should be CALL proc_empname_refcursor(:deptId). see example [here](http://parveengupta.blogspot.com/2011/03/hibernate-stored-procedure-call.html)

Comment: If I remove the "?" then I am getting this exception: `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_EMPNAME_REFCURSOR'`

Comment: are you able to sort out the problem as I am also getting the same issue while calling a stored function via hibernate