# How to call a MySQL stored procedure with multiple OUT parameters using JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have following Mysql stored procedure with only OUT parameters, How I can call this stored procedure through hibernate in with only OUT Parameters?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBNAME.getStatistics (OUT A BIGINT UNSIGNED, OUT B BIGINT UNSIGNED, OUT C BIGINT UNSIGNED)
    BEGIN

        SELECT count(*) into A   from  DBNAME.Table1 where id =0;
        SELECT count(*) into B   from DBNAME.Table2 where id>0 and id<4;
        SELECT count(*) into C   from  DBNAME.Table3 where id>4;
    END
```

EDIT

**Following code I used in java to test the call of MySQL stored procedure (with only OUT Parameters) through hibernate(Java):**

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

Connection connection = session.connection();
CallableStatement callable = null;

try {

callable = connection.prepareCall("{Call DBNAME.getStatistics(?,?,?)}");

// three ?,?,? means three OUT parameter. 
// If any parameters is IN type of
// Lets say the first one then use : callable.setInt(1, 10);

    callable.registerOutParameter(1, Types.BIGINT);
    callable.registerOutParameter(2, Types.BIGINT);
    callable.registerOutParameter(3, Types.BIGINT);
    callable.executeUpdate();

    int value1 = callable.getInt(1);
    int value2 = callable.getInt(2);
    int value3 = callable.getInt(3);


    System.out.println(value1);
    System.out.println(value2);
    System.out.println(value3);
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with Hibernate. I have seen this done before

```
Connection connection = session.connection();
CallableStatement callable = null;
callable = connection.prepareCall("execute [procedure] ?");
callable.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
callable.execute();
int id = callable.getInt(1);
```

Which has worked. See [Retrieving a value from Stored Procedure using Native SQL Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347409/retrieving-a-value-from-stored-procedure-using-native-sql-hibernate) for more context.

Comment: Thanks Aamir, Yes, You are right, this approach worked, but this approach is not very clear with the given explanation, so I added the answer of my test code as complete code of the question I asked above.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very detailed article about [how you can call MySQL stored procedures and database functions from Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedures-and-functions-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), but I'll write a short summary here as well.

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
.createStoredProcedureQuery("getStatistics")
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("A", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("B", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("C", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

query.execute();

Long a = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue("A");
Long b = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue("B");
Long c = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue("C");
```