# Hibernate 4 upgrade, COMMIT not being issued

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, postgresql-9.1

I am attempting to upgrade our code base from Hibernate 3.6 to 4.0 (just as a first step into getting us more up to date). I am hitting an issue where a COMMIT is not being issued even though we are calling the commit() after making sure the transaction is isActive().

When running some queries successfully against the Postgres database, I see this in the Postgres logs:

```
2014-12-30 20:09:39 CST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits=3
2014-12-30 20:09:39 CST LOG:  execute S_1: BEGIN
2014-12-30 20:09:39 CST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: -- This script........
```

Notice the BEGIN there, and then here's an example of the simple commit call:

```
    if (sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
        sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

I have debugged down into AbstractTransactionImpl and am looking at a Jdbc4Connection commit() method, and see that the actual COMMIT call is being skipped.....but I don't know why. Here's the if statement that this is failing on (it is in AbstractJdbc2Connection).

```
if (protoConnection.getTransactionState() != ProtocolConnection.TRANSACTION_IDLE)
    executeTransactionCommand(commitQuery);
```

So, apparently our transactionstate is == ProtocolConnection.TRANSACTION_IDLE. However, I'm not entirely sure what that entails, and why are we getting this issue when the transaction says it isActive()?

NOTE: this same exact code worked for us on Hibernate 3.6.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I debugged further, and it looks like there are many ProtocoalConnectionImpl objects being constructed, does that indicate a problem on our software side that is doing something it shouldn't? Like does that indicate that we're opening connections that are just hanging around? Thanks for any more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was doing something incorrect (surprise). There's a good reason that the TransactionState was showing as TRANSACTION_IDLE and not issuing a commit.

I had seen in multiple places on the internetz where people were getting access to a JDBC connection in the new Hibernate 4.x land by getting access to the underlying ConnectionProvider (sort of like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21271019/115694).

However, the problem with doing that is that you are getting a BRAND NEW connection....instead of the connection associated with the *current* session. This is a pretty big no-no, or at least for us it was.

You do have to in fact do what the person says in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526626/115694

Basically, you MUST use the Work API.