# StatelessSession#connection() deprecated on Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, database-connection, stateless-session

I'm cleaning up some warnings, and I came up on some code using the `connection()` method of `StatelessSession`, whose deprecation doc says they missed it when deprecation the same method on `Session`.

Now, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526556/session-connection-deprecated-on-hibernate) point to the `doWork` method on `Session`, but no such method exists on `StatelessSession`. So, how is one supposed to fix this deprecation?

Answer (score 0):

The [StatelessSession.connection()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html#connection%28%29) method goal was to:

> Return the current JDBC connection associated with this instance.

The `StatelessSession` inherits this method from [SessionImplementor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor.html#connection%28%29), which is not deprecated, so it's safe to use it. Even if it's going to be removed from `StatelessSession`, you will still have this method from the `SessionImplementor`.

Comment: That is just not true. There's `SessionImplementor` is not inherited by `StatelessSession`. The cast might work because the class that _implements_ `StatelessSession` happens to implement `SessionImplementor` as well, but relying on such a cast is extremely brittle -- much more so than keeping the deprecated method call.

Comment: You should raise this question on the Hibernate mailing list too. One option would be to have access to the current TransactionImplementator, but that's not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    StatelessSession statelessSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
    try {
        ((StatelessSessionImpl) statelessSession).getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection().setTransactionIsolation(TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```