# Is there a way to use Postgresql copy (loading CSV in table) from Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

In my current application I am using Hibernate + PostgreSQL. For a particular case I need to use the `COPY` functionality available in postgres to load data from CSV file. Is there any way to use `COPY` using Hibernate.

```
Postgres version : 9.4
Hibernate version : 5.0.6
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I'm new to Hibernate, so couldn't do much with Hibernate.
I am able to do this using jdbc type 4 connection. If you are interested in that I can share that code, however it will be irrelevant to the topic

Comment: Hibernate will not support that. But you _can_ use `copy from stdin` from JDBC using the [`CopyManager` API](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html). See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648947/how-to-indicate-a-session-instance-to-postgresql-copymanager

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the reference link, gave me a way forward.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @a-horse-with-no-name comment, I put together following code as `session.doWork` is deprecated.

```
SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
SessionImplementor sessImpl = (SessionImplementor) session;
Connection conn = null;
conn = sessImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection();
CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) conn);
File tf =File.createTempFile("temp-file", "tmp"); 
String tempPath =tf.getParent();
File tempFile = new File(tempPath + File.separator + filename);
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(tempFile);
copyManager.copyIn("copy testdata (col1, col2, col3) from  STDIN with csv", fileReader );
```

Hope this helps readers.