# Executing jOOQ statements inside Hibernate transaction

Tags: hibernate, jooq

Say I use both Hibernate (JPA) and jOOQ for my data persistence.

I want to open transaction via EntityManager to do some work.

Then I use jOOQ for selecting and updating few tables in the same transaction that I opened with EntityManager, and I commit or roll back all the operations above.

I don't use Spring or any other container transaction manager.

```
try {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    //do JPA stuff here fetch from FB update entity
    DLSConext - want to use JOOQ DSL for crud operation
    em.getTransaction().commit()
} catch (Exception e) {
    em.getTransaction().rollback();  //All Hibernate and jooq operation should rool back
}
```

**Edit**
So How do I do it?
Say for example I using jOOQ for some updates  and I then I want Hibernate to find an entity, but I also want Hibernate to see the updates done by jOOQ few lines before fetching an entity.

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493495/getting-database-connection-in-pure-jpa-setup . I would still advise you not to go down this road. Mixing JPA/ORM and raw SQL./JDBC is bad for your caches (the session itself, the L2 cache, query cache) and leads to pretty hard to debug issues unless you're sure you're not manipulating / flushing data "behind the back of JPA/Hibernate", which is hard to prove as you do it, and harder still to enforce in future evolutions.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really specific to jOOQ but applies to all mixing of JPA with native SQL. You have to make sure that all of Hibernate's caches are flushed before you run any jOOQ (or JDBC, etc.) queries.

If you execute your queries using jOOQ directly, you could do this inside of jOOQ's [`ConnectionProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html) SPI, which is invoked by jOOQ every time just before jOOQ wants to execute a query. Or, alternatively, use Hibernate's [`Session.doWork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526626/521799) API like this:

```java
public static Work jOOQWork(Session session, Consumer<DSLContext> consumer) {
    session.flush();
    session.doWork(connection -> consumer.accept(DSL.using(connection)));
}
```

And then:

```java
jOOQWork(session, ctx -> 
    ctx.insertInto(TABLE)
       .columns(TABLE.COL)
       .values(1)
       .execute()
);
```

Note that `Session.flush()` is required here, although it probably shouldn't be, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14209

If you execute your queries via `EntityManager::createNativeQuery`, `EntityManager::flush` [should be called automatically for you](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-jpa-and-hibernate-define-the-auto-flush-mode/).

Comment: Thank you. I need to set jooq's connectionProvider each time I open Hibernate session? also does it mean jooq execution is in the same transaction I started with Hibernate?

Comment: @user1409534: Well, you could obtain a JDBC connection from Hibernate, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526556/521799. Then just wrap that with `DSL.using(connection)` in jOOQ, and make sure that your logic obtaining the JDBC connection takes care of flushing...

Comment: @user1409534: I've updated my answer with an example