# HibernateException not subclass of Throwable error

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I had to replace the Hibernate call `Connection conn = sessionImpl.connection()` with the following, due to ".connection()" being deprecated in Hibernate. ref: [session.connection() deprecated on Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526556/session-connection-deprecated-on-hibernate) A try;catch; is required, as `doWork()` throws a HibernateException.

```
try {
    session.doWork(
        new Work() {
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException 
            { 
                doSomething(connection); 
            }
        }
    );
} catch (HibernateException e) {
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting the following in Eclipse:

> No exception of type HibernateException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

As far as I can tell, HibernateException chains back to Throwable, so I don't know what it's talking about.

I'm using hibernate-core 6.1.0

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Update/Fix**

So it turns out I didn't have the right library on my classpath. HibernateException extends jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException I did have the following in my POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But I did NOT have the persistence API in my POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I had checked my POM before, but didn't realize there was a difference between the two. Thanks rzwitserloot for enticing me to look again.

Comment: The compiler isn't lying to you. Possibly you have written your own class, perhaps to try this out as example, and you named it `HibernateException`.

Comment: Thanks. This is an inherited solution, but I did search for a custom HibernateException class that a prior dev may have added, but couldn't find one. When I trace  the `catch (HibernateException e)` object, it's pointing to 

`package org.hibernate;
public class HibernateException extends PersistenceException`
which extends from
`package javax.persistence;
public class PersistenceException extends RuntimeException`. These are both Hibernate packages, not something built in the solution

Comment: The compiler error has only two explanations: [A] HibernateException or PersistenceException isn't on the classpath, or [B] you have a class named HibernateException in the same package or otherwise imported it, and it isn't hibernate-core's exception.