# Some basic JPA+Hibernate Questions?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have some basic questions:

1) How many xml files involved in JPA+Hibernate combination, if JPA annotations were used? i am having just persistence.xml.

2) Is hibernate.cfg.xml needed, if i use JPA annotaions. Because, i didnt added it till now.

3) Shall anyone give me the list of basic JAR file names, in case of using JPA 2.0 & Hibernate!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **1) How many xml files involved in
>   JPA+Hibernate combination, if JPA
>   annotations were used? i am having
>   just persistence.xml.**

Usually this one file is enough, annotated entities will be automatically picked up through class path scanning. But you can define external mapping files (an example is available [on this page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/guides/jpa/tutorial.html)). The mechanism is this:

```
<persistence-unit name="xyz">
    <mapping-file>../orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <!-- ... -->
</persistence-unit>
```

> **2) Is hibernate.cfg.xml needed, if i
>   use JPA annotaions. Because, i didnt
>   added it till now.**

hibernate.cfg.xml is proprietary hibernate stuff and not needed for jpa.
In JPA, you can use `<properties>` to configure vendor-specific properties. Example:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
</properties>
```

See this document for [Hibernate / JPA configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html)

> **3) Shall anyone give me the list of basic JAR file names, in case of using
>   JPA 2.0 & Hibernate!!!**

you should use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

(see [this directory](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/) for the latest version, scan [this file](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/maven-metadata.xml) for the latest occurrence of `*.*.*-Final` or just read the [Hibernate web site](http://www.hibernate.org/))

You will also need to add the JBoss repository to the pom.xml or settings.xml:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
  ...
</repositories>
```

that will automatically add everything else that's needed, see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999077/how-to-compile-hibernate-project-with-maven/2999166#2999166) for more details.

If you don't want to use maven, you can use the [release bundles](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/) provided by sourceforge.

Comment: I would just add that if you're not using Maven, you should get  [release bundles](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/) from SourceForge. +1 anyway of course.